# Display Output in Rows Not Columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the answers to come out side by side, not on top of each other. How do I do that?

```
n=0

while 1:

    n=int(input("Enter N="))
    if n > 0:
             break
    print("Error. please enter only positive numbers.")
i=1
print("\nThe divisors of N are:",)
while i <=n:
    if (n%i) == 0:
        print(i,)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the line

```
        print(i,)
```

to

```
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.stdout.write` in place of `print`